# how to get the Absolute Path for symlink file?

Tags: perl

#  test-> a.pl

```
my $file = '/home/joe/test';
if ( -f $file && -l $file )  {
    print readlink( $file ) ;
}
```

how to get the Absolute Path for symlink file ?

Comment: are you saying you want the absolute path of the symlink or the absolute path of the file the symlink points to?

Comment: absolute path of the file the symlink points to

Comment: So actually you just want to know how to get the absolute path for a given pathname, because you already know how to use `readlink()` to get a path to the pointed-to file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527638/what-perl-modules-do-i-use-to-obtain-an-absolute-path-including-filename-from/1527773#1527773.  (In a sense your question is a dupe of this since brian's answer is the right answer for any OS, not just Windows.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Cwd](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) provides such functionality by [abs_path](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html#abs_path-and-friends).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Cwd 'abs_path';

my $file='/home/joe/test';
if( -f $file && -l $file ) {
    print abs_path($file);
}
```

Comment: Carefull, that will likely go wrong when UTF-8 filenames are in use. In that case something like `Encode::decode_utf8(Cwd::abs_path($file));` may be needed!

Answer (score 2):

if you use File::Spec rel2abs along with readlink you'll get the abs path even if it's a symlink to another symlink

```
use File::Spec;

$path = File::Spec->rel2abs( readlink($file) ) ;
```

Comment: File::Spec's rel2abs doesn't seem to work with multiple links. Cwd's abs_path works. Try `touch /tmp/target; ln -s target /tmp/link1; ln -s link1 /tmp/link2` and compare `perl -MFile::Spec -e '$f="/tmp/link2"; print "$f: ",  File::Spec->rel2abs( readlink($f) ), "\n"'`with `perl -M'Cwd "abs_path"' -e '$f="/tmp/link2"; print "$f : ", abs_path($f), "\n"'`

Comment: Thanks for proving that specifying soft links without the path prefix when you're not in the same directory will break things and is, therefore, a bad thing to do ;-)

Comment: Should I also point out that the OP asked for the ["absolute path of the file the symlink points to"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887672/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-for-symlink-file#comment-5437184) and *not* the canonical path (which is an absolute path but _not necessarily_ the file asked for)?