# how to get the path which symlinked to, using perl?

Tags: perl

I have below symlink, and i need to get the source path of the symlink, see below example

```
/home/folder/linked --> /var/log/source ( /var/log/source  symlink to /home/folder/linked)
```

how can i get `/var/log/source` path using Perl ?

Comment: @mob That's not a duplicate.

Comment: yes. it's not :C

Comment: I mean, the second answer happens to answer this question (use `readlink`), but both the question and the accepted answer are different.

Comment: anyway use Cwd 'abs_path'; this helped me

Comment: `abs_path` is different. That will completely resolve all symbolic links anywhere in the path, not just the immediate target of the last path component.

Comment: ... but if that solves your problem, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887672/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-for-symlink-file is a better duplicate.

Comment: since there is only one symlink i think it solves but still under testing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the unprocessed value of a symlink, use [`readlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readlink.html). This could be a path relative to the symlink's location. This could be a path to another symlink.

If you want an path that's not a symlink, use [Cwd](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cwd)'s `abs_path`. This will return a fully resolved absolute path (i.e. an absolute path that doesn't use any symlinks).

Comment: Entirely correct answer. I often find that `readlink` and `lstat` go well together.